# What type of wire connector is this?

Tags: wiring, electric-motor, connectors

I'm attempting to replace the thermal fuse in the motor for my [Rigid shop vac (model number WD 1280)](https://www.ridgid.com/us/en/12-gal-wet-dry-vac-with-detachable-blower). I bought it used; it's clearly been worked and possibly left to the elements for some time. I'm completely new to this type of work so any help is appreciated. As you can see in the attached pictures, the wire connectors are fairly corroded. So corroded that while attempting to a detach a switch wire (female end) from the motor, the male wire connector snapped. My questions are:

(1) What type of male connector is this? It would need to fit into the plastic casing.
[image]
[image]

(2) Where can I buy them online? I couldn't locate them on the websites for the big box stores, but perhaps I wasn't using the correct terminology.

(3) What should I use to crimp the fuse lead and the copper wire? I don't want to solder. Do the fuse leads and copper wire need to be to be touching? Should I use a crimp sleeve like the one pictured below? If so, what's it called?
[image]

(4) All of the wire connectors in the motor are corroded. How should I clean these?

I appreciate any help.

Christopher

Comment: Usually known as 1/4 inch disconnects.  Do not know if they come in pieces for repair, the inside metal from the plastic cover.

Comment: Websites to buy from - electronics suppliers - Digi-Key, Mouser, Newark and others.  **Clear signs that it's probably pointless to do so** - the corrosion on the coils means the varnish (that is the insulation on "magnet wire") isn't intact, so the coils are no longer insulated turn-from-turn, so it's scrap. Or were you planning to unwind, re-varnish, and re-wind it?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not wedded to salvaging it. The fuse was actually working--based on a test with a multimeter--before one of the leads snapped to render the fuse unusable. Then I had problems with the wiring snapping from one of the male disconnects. Sounds like you're saying that one just can't wipe off the corrosion from the top. I don't think I have the skill in working with wire to revarnish and put this thing back together. Was just hoping to replace the disconnects and fuse.

Comment: You can add red motor coil varnish to add insulation no harsh cleaners or rough stuff like sand paper or wire brushes but a soft brush shouldn’t harm it and a small can of motor varnish it will be good as new, this is all I need to do many times if the motor is functional.

Comment: Thanks, Ed. What is mean by the coils "turning"/"turn-from-turn"? Is all that wire spinning in there? (sorry, don't know much bout electrical engineering)

Comment: Also, even if do add the motor coil varnish, I think I still need to find those male disconnects. I've been looking all over--even in Ridgid hardware catalogs--and can't track them down. I've contacted Ridgid so we'll see if they can hook me up with the disconnects. I really don't want them to send me a whole new vac out of this on account of all the plastic waste.

Answer (score 1):

That is a male quick disconnect / spade(like flat shovel)connector finding one with the additional supports may be tough as that may be an OEM part, I have 1/2 a dozen different styles and none are like that it will probably be a smaller wire size also at max blue but most probably Red, most compression connectors like this come in small =red, medium= blue, and yellow = large
Off the top of my head yellow is for ~14-12 gauge
Blue is ~18-20 and red is moor like wires from components to ~ 28 awg again that is a swag from past use.